# The rapture. The kingdom of God, 2 Cor 5:1

Tags: heaven, kingdom-of-god, god, rapture

The rapture. We will hear trumpets we will see the chariots with the disciples and Angels coming down and all of the believers will be going to heaven it says in the Bible that in heaven there Will be streets paved in gold be no pain there will be no sorrow he will have crown of jewels from all your good works through your life I'll be mansions.

But my question is: **Why would you need any of those tangible things if your flesh is not going with you it's just your spirit.**

> 2 Cor 5:1, 4 - For we know that if the tent of our earthly house
> should be destroyed, we have a building from God, a house not made
> with hands, eternal in the heavens. ... And indeed, being in the tent
> we groan, being burdened, because we do not wish to be unclothed but
> to be clothed, so that the mortal may be swallowed up by life.

Comment: Please provide evidence that only our spirit goes to heaven. Paul in 1 for 15 days we will receive heavenly bodies.  You hav provided no text

Comment: Genesis 3:19. 2 Corinthians 4:7 2 Corinthians 5:4 Isaiah 38:12 but mostly 2 Corinthians 5:1

Answer (score 4):

Our mortal flesh will not go to heaven. As 1 Cor 15:50 [Dottard mentions this].

But, **1 John 3:2**

> "We shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is".

Here is a recognisable body. And as we shall be like him, which gives us clues as to what we will be like, we will be  recognisable.

**Phillipians 3:21**

> "[Jesus] will transform our lowly body to be like his  glorious body".

If we think our present bodies are real, fine, but the reality that our future bodies will experience will be glorious.

**John 20:27**

> "..see my hands,".

Jesus has a literal body. Not a "spiritual" and therefore, not quite real body. Spiritual in the sense of immortal, not mortal.

**Luke 24:39**

> "For a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have".

Here we see in some aspects a very similar structure to what we have now.

**Romans 8:11**

> "If the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through his Spirit who dwells in you".

It is our bodies that are raised. Our mortal bodies are given the spiritual life of Christ. Christ perfect, holy, glorious and bearing the image of the man of heaven. 1 Cor 15:49.

**John 20:26**

> "Although the doors were locked, Jesus came and stood *among them*.

Heavenly bodies are not tied to the laws of physics as we experience them now. But new possibilities will open up.

**1 Corinthians 15:43**

> "It is sown in dishonour; it is raised in glory. It is sown in weakness; it is raised in power".

Here dishonour is the darkness of sin [John 1:5]. And God's sinless glory "the true light". [John 1:9].

Answer (score 2):

Actually, 2 Cor 5:1-4 does NOT say that only our spirits go to heaven.  Indeed, the teaching of 2 Cor 5:1-4 says the same things as 1 Cor 15:35-49, namely that the resurrected saints will receive a "heavenly body", ie, one that is NOT made with hands.

In 2 Cor 5:1-4 specifically say that our "tent" (= earthly body) will be replaced with a "building from God", ie, a heavenly body as per 1 Cor 15:35-49.

Answer (score 2):

It would be improper to use an unscriptural term, “Rapture” to use to describe the “Resurrection” of the dead as in the OP.

It is true that “flesh and blood” shall not go to heaven (1 Cor 15:50).

But that doesn’t mean that the resurrected saints will not have any “body”. The Scripture says:

> “If there is a physical body, there is also a ***spiritual* body**” (1
> Cor 15:44).

The resurrected saints will have a spiritual body (“a building from God, a house not made with hands, eternal” – 2 Cor 5:1) just as the resurrected Jesus has a spiritual body now, a “glorious body” (Phil 3:21); “the body of the Lord” (1 Cor 11:29; interlinear).

Jesus Christ is the express image of God the Father (Heb 1:3; 2 Cor 4:4; Col 1:15). So if the Lord of glory has a glorious body, then definitely God the Father has a spiritual body too (John 14:9).

But Jesus clarifies that He is Spirit **not** in the sense of a “ghost” or an “apparition” but with a **real** spiritual “body” (Luke 24:39).

We are given to understand that many things in the world are modeled and patterned after the heavenly things (Heb 8:5).

Hence, it is common sense and logical to think that if the physical world can be so vivid and beautiful with so much variety, then the spiritual world would be a thousand times more vivid, beautiful and varied.

So, the spiritual world is not simply an imaginary concept. It is a real world.

Comment: Why do you write that "rapture" is unscriptural? The English word, rapture, comes from the Latin term, *rapturo*, which was translated from the Greek word, *harpazo* (see Strong's Greek 726).

Comment: @Dieter – May be you have a point there but then I wonder why we don’t find that term in many of the well-known English translations.

Comment: This is because many translations are based on the Latin Vulgate. This has resulted in this Latin word being added to the English language. Similarly, the Greek word *baptismos*, which means dip or immerse, was also added to English as "baptize."

Answer (score 1):

Who said that a) “gold” and gem-paved pavements in Heavenly Jerusalem aren’t metaphors? Then also angels’ wings must be made of physical feathers, have you seen any of them fallen on earth? and b) human bodies will not be reunited to their bodies at resurrection? Resurrection of bodies, i.e. their reunification with their souls is a standard Christian doctrine.

Comment: "Tzitzit are specially knotted ritual fringes, or tassels, worn in antiquity by Israelites and today by observant Jews and Samaritans. Tzitzit are usually attached to the four corners of the tallit gadol." The four corners of the tallit have also been referred to as "wings" (presumably without feathers). But I agree with the concept that gold, which has historically been precious to humans, is simply paving materials as far as God's kingdom is concerned. Jesus said as much with his comment that if a person can't be trusted with earthly wealth, who will trust them with "true" wealth.